# ScoreAttained condition throws arithmatic exception - OptaPlanner

Tags: exception, math, optaplanner

Using HARDSOFTBIGDECIMAL score.

In the config file I set scoreAttained to 0hard/0soft.

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(Unknown Source)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.buildin.hardsoftbigdecimal.HardSoftBigDecimalScoreDefinition.calculateTimeGradient(HardSoftBigDecimalScoreDefinition.java:96)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.buildin.hardsoftbigdecimal.HardSoftBigDecimalScoreDefinition.calculateTimeGradient(HardSoftBigDecimalScoreDefinition.java:27)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.termination.ScoreAttainedTermination.calculateSolverTimeGradient(ScoreAttainedTermination.java:50)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.termination.OrCompositeTermination.calculateSolverTimeGradient(OrCompositeTermination.java:69)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.termination.OrCompositeTermination.calculateSolverTimeGradient(OrCompositeTermination.java:69)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.termination.PhaseToSolverTerminationBridge.calculatePhaseTimeGradient(PhaseToSolverTerminationBridge.java:80)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchSolverPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchSolverPhase.java:60)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.runSolverPhases(DefaultSolver.java:190)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:155)
```

EDIT:

solved the problem by extending HARDSOFTBIGDECIMALSCOREDEFINITION and overriding calculateTimeGradient(..) method. Here when the divide method is called on BigDecimal, I rounded up.

Comment: Can you post your call?

Comment: @Drewness [Call is here](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/score/buildin/hardsoftbigdecimal/HardSoftBigDecimalScoreDefinition.java#L96)

Comment: [Jira issue created](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-225) @AliShah Pull request to fix it welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are more than likely dividing two numbers that have an exact quotient that is infinite.

For example: `1/3 = 0.33333...`

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

> When a MathContext object is supplied with a precision setting of 0
>   (for example, MathContext.UNLIMITED), arithmetic operations are exact,
>   as are the arithmetic methods which take no MathContext object. (This
>   is the only behavior that was supported in releases prior to 5.)
>
> As a corollary of computing the exact result, the rounding mode
>   setting of a MathContext object with a precision setting of 0 is not
>   used and thus irrelevant. In the case of divide, the exact quotient
>   could have an infinitely long decimal expansion; for example, 1
>   divided by 3.
>
> If the quotient has a nonterminating decimal expansion and the
>   operation is specified to return an exact result, an
>   ArithmeticException is thrown. Otherwise, the exact result of the
>   division is returned, as done for other operations.

So to fix this you need to provide a scale of precision for `BigDecimal`, like so:

`x.divide(y, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)`

Where `2` is the precision and `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` is the rounding mode.

You can read more about rounding [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_UP).

Comment: Great answer. As a library, which RoundingMode should we use? I am european, so I am thinking HALF_UP, but our American users/developers will prefer HALF_EVEN and other users/developers from other locale's might want something else... On the other hand I strongly dislike being locale dependent in these kinds of calculations.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet - Well I'm in the US an I use HALF_UP, but I guess it really depends on your situation. I can see your predicament but it's hard for me to say one way or the other. Sorry!